# How to Pass BackSlash at end of string?

Tags: php

I m trying to delete one image using unlink function.

But path creates error to pass. My syntax is as below.

```
unlink('customer\'.$user_id."\book\".$id);
```

But this will generate error here.

Please help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The backslash can escape itself. Both in double and single quoted string context.

Comment: Check the formatting of your question. What error?

Comment: You should use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` to support both linux & windows

Comment: You can use slashes in Windows as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
unlink('customer\\'.$user_id."\\book\\".$id);
```

Comment: Ok I will try this one

Answer (score 0):

Use this (Use Backslash)

```
unlink("customer/".$user_id."/book/".$id)
```